# jQuery how to pass #output to variable to use in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First, I'm sorry about posting a question. I don't even know how to make a search for this, since my knowledge about Javascript nor jQuery is 0%. I tried searching the automatic questions that show up when you type your question, but I couldn't find the answer yet.

I have this piece of code to drag an image around inside a div:

```
$(function() {
    $('.headerCoupleBackground').imagedrag({
        input: "#output",
        position: "middle",
        attribute: "html"
    });
}
```

So, I can show this on my HTML page by posting:

```
<span id="output"></span>
```

But, what I like to do, is to show the created output inside a hidden input field value. I think I need to change the 'input: #output'-part, but I really have no idea how to change that or what I need to do to fix my problem. Instead of saving it inside #output, I thought I needed to store it inside a variable, but I didn't got that to work either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the HTML to an input

```
<input id="output" type='hidden'>
```

And the attribute to `value`

```
$('.headerCoupleBackground').imagedrag({
    input: "#output",
    position: "middle",
    attribute: "value"
});
```

According to [the docs](http://puneetk.com/jq-image-drag/), the default value for attribute is value, so you can omit it entirely:

```
$('.headerCoupleBackground').imagedrag({
    input: "#output",
    position: "middle"
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question. If you can explain more what you want to achieve it would help. Try this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="output">
```